# How to trigger response for Custom Intent?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I created an Alexa 'riddle' skill recently and I'm having trouble with the utterances. I created an intent "GetRiddleIntent" then associated a few utterances e.g. "riddle me this" with that intent. I did not include any intent slots. When I test my skill, I have to use the invocation name in order to bring back results from lambda.

The built in intents work upon invocation e.g. "LaunchRequest" & "Amazon HelpRequest" but none of the sample utterances for my custom intent return any results, I keep getting the "There was a problem with the requested skills response" as a result.

This is for a riddle skill being implemented using JAVA and ask-sdk V2.

I've tried implementing the handler responsible for the riddles from scratch.

Edited the Riddle string to ensure there are no characters that might cause any response failure.

Messed around with changing "shouldEndSession" to true and to false (currently have it set back to false)

I've also copied the error response from the developer console into my lambda configurations for a more detailed error log and nothing points specifically to my code per-say. I get a java.lang.NullPointerException which points to errors in built in libraries e.g. com.amazon.ask.SkillStreamHandler.handleRequest(SkillStreamHandler.java:71)

I've also looked at the following sample skills in V2 for assistance but none have helped. https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/tree/2.0.x/samples

```
package lambda.riddle.handlers;

import static com.amazon.ask.request.Predicates.intentName;

import java.util.Optional;

import com.amazon.ask.dispatcher.request.handler.HandlerInput;
import com.amazon.ask.dispatcher.request.handler.RequestHandler;
import com.amazon.ask.model.Response;

import riddle_generator.Riddle;
import riddle_generator.GenerateRiddles;



public class GetRiddleIntentHandler implements RequestHandler 
{
  public boolean canHandle(HandlerInput input)
  {
    return input.matches(intentName("GetRiddleIntent"));
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Response> handle(HandlerInput input) 
  {

    String speechText, repromptText;

    speechText = "I am caucasian, internet famous and best known for my catchphrase, catch me outside how about that. Who am I?";
    repromptText = "I am caucasian, internet famous and best known for my catchphrase, catch me outside how about that. Who am I?";
    return input.getResponseBuilder()
        .withSimpleCard("RiddleSession", speechText)
        .withSpeech(speechText)
        .withReprompt(repromptText)
        .withShouldEndSession(false)
        .build();
  }
}
```

I should get the speechText as a response in my develop console but instead get a "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" message.

[image: Lambda Console Error Log]

[image: Developer console output]

Below is the error Response:

```
{
  "request": {
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.338924d9-8cf9-448a-85a2-6a8bacc5e1be",
        "timestamp": "2019-02-02T12:01:04Z",
        "locale": "en-GB",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This response is sent by Alexa either when your Lamba function crashes or when it returns an invalid JSON. Increase the amount of logs in your code. Capture the JSON request sent by Alexa and replay it in the lambda console to ensure the function does not return an error

Comment: @SébastienStormacq What do you mean by increasing the number of logs in my code? I'm fairly new to this so I don't really understand that or know what to do. The JSON editor, i have checked, doesn't say there are any errors. 

The error response I included in my question has already been tested with my lambda console (I added an image of the output given after it was replayed in the console)  so i believe i've already carried out your suggestion bar the logs bit which I don't understand

Comment: @Blank I believe the suggestion being made is "modify your code to write more progress/status/debug messages to the log" so you can understand how far your code is progressing and what paths are being taken before the exception is thrown.  As it is now, the exception is the first thing logged as soon as the function is invoked, so there's not much info to go on.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the clarification but I'm not too sure how I'm to go about writing more debug messages that'll be displayed on the logs, do you mean system.out.println statements? or what?

Comment: Yes. The stdout stream is sent to cloud watch logs. So everything you print on System.out in Java will be visible in the log. Please have look at Lambda documentation about Logging for Java at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html

Comment: @SébastienStormacq Just tested out your suggestion and there doesn't seem to be any difference in the log output, added logger dependencies to my pom file as well.

Comment: what about just adding `System.out.println()` at key points in your code to check what is the execution path then ?